# How can I make a roc curve

Tags: conv-neural-network

i have a project and i make a convolutional network and then i try to tired to make roc curve in matlab but i got this error in augmentedImageDatastore :Error using augmentedImageDatastore/parseInputs
The argument 'gray2rgb' is a string scalar or character
vector and does not match any parameter names. It failed
validation for the argument 'Y'.

`imageSize = [28 28 1];

trainset = augmentedImageDatastore(imageSize, trainData, 'gray2rgb');
testset = augmentedImageDatastore(imageSize, testData, 'gray2rgb' );

`